# Always getting 404 response when using service with scope in actix-web

Tags: rust, actix-web

I am writing an application using Actix Web and when configuring the routes i wanted to use scopes. The problem is that I can't seem to get them working like they should according to the documentation. Even though everything seems correct I always get a 404 response.

```
#[get("/")]
async fn show_users() -> HttpResponse {
    HttpResponse::Ok().finish()
}

#[actix_web::main]
async fn main() -> std::io::Result<()> {
    HttpServer::new(|| {
        App::new()
        .service(show_users)
        .service(web::scope("/users").service(show_users))
    })
    .bind(("127.0.0.1", 8080))?
    .run()
    .await
}
```

I can access the function through `localhost:8080` but not `localhost:8080/users`

Isn't this basically the same as the first code example here?

https://actix.rs/docs/application#using-an-application-scope-to-compose-applications

Comment: Do you need the trailing slash on `/users/` in the URL?

Comment: No. It doesn't work and you shouldn't do it according to this: https://actix.rs/docs/url-dispatch/#resource-pattern-syntax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The change that needs to be made is removing the `/` from the get.

Like this:

```
#[get("")]
async fn show_users() -> HttpResponse {
    HttpResponse::Ok().finish()
}

#[actix_web::main]
async fn main() -> std::io::Result<()> {
    HttpServer::new(|| {
        App::new()
        .service(show_users)
        .service(web::scope("/users").service(show_users))
    })
    .bind(("127.0.0.1", 8080))?
    .run()
    .await
}
```

Answer (score 0):

just add NormalizePath

https://docs.rs/actix-web/4.5.1/actix_web/middleware/struct.NormalizePath.html

```rust
#[get("/")]
async fn show_users() -> HttpResponse {
    HttpResponse::Ok().finish()
}

#[actix_web::main]
async fn main() -> std::io::Result<()> {
    HttpServer::new(|| {
        App::new()
        .wrap(NormalizePath::new(TrailingSlash::Always))
        .service(web::scope("/users").service(show_users))
    })
    .bind(("127.0.0.1", 8080))?
    .run()
    .await
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).